# No such file or directory error in macOS in recovery mode

Tags: macos, recovery

I am using macOS Catalina (10.15) and I'm trying to backup my Mac home folder to my current SSD drive through recovery mode. I am planning on saving data and then cleaning the drive so that my Mac can hopefully work again. When I'm trying to copy my home folder to my SSD drive using terminal through this command:

```
cp -r -v /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD\ -\ Data/Users/username/ /Volumes/Container\ disk23
```

It starts to go through and list all of my files on my home folder such as all my downloads and what is on my desktop. However, it is giving me that there is no such file or directory for each item. Does anyone know what could be going wrong or are there any solutions to help successfully upload all of data on my home folder to my SSD drive.

FYI, since I am in recovery mode, I just cannot drag my home folder into terminal.

Comment: What about your computer is not working? Is it possible the problem is with the drive itself? Can you test the drive?

Comment: Also, there are odd spaces in your command text that I think should not be there. Can you please use the EDIT button, then look at the command you've entered and confirm it is exactly the command you're running, and also use some of the formatting tools available there to help that code fit properly?

Comment: For some reason my computer is not able to log me in all the way so I'm assuming it is the drive. I also checked, and I believe that it is corrupted and there is no way for me to repair it using disk utility. I also believe that the command is also correct. The weird spaces is because there is a space in the name such as Container\ disk23 means the ssd name is Container disk23

Comment: Do those spaces need to be enclosed by quotes perhaps? Does the command know how to handle the spaces without being told they are strings?

Comment: @music2myear No, the escapes (backslashes) looks correct; quotes could be used instead of escapes, but using both would not work. Harvey Li: try using `ls` to view the files (e.g. `ls -l /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD\ -\ Data/Users/username/`) and see if that shows anything useful about them. Also, including some exact error messages might help clarify what's going on.

Comment: Cool. I am not as familiar with the Mac terminal.

Comment: Hi Gordon, ls doesn't really show anything much that would be useful to me. It just lists everything in my home folder like desktop, downloads, and additional random things in my home folder. More specifically about the error message is that it just states "No such file or directory". For example: cp: /Volumes/Container disk23/Library/Containers/com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX/Data/Downloads/IMG_4079.JPG: No such file or directory

Comment: @HarveyLi That error points to a problem on the destination disk, not the source disk, which is extremely important information. Do all of the error messages list "/Volumes/Container disk23" rather than "/Volumes/Macintosh HD - Data"? Do any of them give errors on directories, or just files? What format is the destination volume? After the attempted copy, what does `ls` show on the destination volume? You should edit your question to include this information.

Comment: @GordonDavisson 1. I believe that it is just files or should be mostly files that are getting errors. 2. I'm confused about the format of the destination volume. What do you mean by that? 3. After I attempted to copy, ls shows only a few files that downloaded.

Comment: @HarveyLi To check the volume format, you can run `mount`; it'll list a bunch of irrelevant things (Recovery mode uses a lot of ramdisks etc), but among them there should be a line referring to Container disk23; something like "/dev/disk2s1 on /Volumes/Container disk23 (**apfs**, local, journaled)". The bit where it says "apfs" or "hfs" or something like that indicates the volume format. You can also get it from Disk Utility by selecting the volume, pressing Command-I (get info), and looking for the "File System" item.

Comment: As for what `ls` shows on the destination volume, what I'm looking for is any sort of pattern of what worked vs what didn't, that might hint at what's causing the problem.

Comment: @GordonDavisson when I ran mount, I saw /dev/disk2s1 on /Volumes/Macintosh HD - Data (apfs, local, journaled, nobrowse). For ls, there doesn't seem to be any sort of pattern. There are only 6 files that really show up.

Comment: @HarveyLi What does `mount` show for /Volumes/Container disk23? Also, what are the 6 files that show up?

Comment: @GordonDavisson the 6 files that show up are 3 .R files and .Rhistory, .eclipse, and .hugindata. For mount I can't find what it shows for /Volumes/Container disk23. Additionally, when I ran mount again, I saw /dev/disk2s1 on /Library/Logs/DiagonsticReports (hfs, local, union, nobrowse)

Comment: Does `ls` on the destination show any of the directories from your home folder (Desktop, Documents, Library, etc), or just individual files? If the directories aren't getting created, that'd explain why you get "No such file or directory" errors on files that're supposed to go *into* those nonexistent directories (and the question becomes, why aren't the directories getting created?). As for the volume format, try `mount | grep disk23` and see if that shows it (BTW, the /dev/disk2s1 entry is irrelevant).

Comment: You could also try `diskutil info /Volumes/Container\ disk23` and look for the "Partition Type:", "File System Personality:", and "Name (User Visible):"